# How to edit default class css in roots theme of wordpress ?(classes like wrap,content,main etc.)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, roots-toolkit

I am a new developer with roots toolkit. How to edit default roots class css wordpress? My question is about the classes like wrap,content,main etc. I also found some default classes for header,footer,aside etc. In which less file I can found this css for editing. Are these classes also the part of bootstrap styles and variables in roots kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edit those in the `base.php` file. Line 15-17:

```
<div class="wrap container" role="document">
    <div class="content row">
      <main class="main" role="main">
```

These are not Bootstrap styles, but more of classes that you can utilize if you want, or delete altogether. By having a wrap there, you can target everything in the initial container, rather than any other container in the site. Same goes for content, or main.